# Can BeginInvoke do the same thing as BackgroundWorker?

Tags: wpf, asynchronous, backgroundworker, begininvoke

Can BeginInvoke do the same thing as a BackgroundWorker ? I mean aren't both having the same goal in the end which is doing async operations in a different thread ?

If i have a WPF windows.. and i want to access database using both methods. Is the effect going to be the same ?

Comment: At the end of the day all BackgroundWorker is a class with an internal Thread. BeginInvoke is used for an entirely different purpose, its not meant to start a thread, it sounds like you should do more research.

Comment: @Ramhound but basically a BackgroundWorker start a thread.. so an async call is like starting a thread. I said IS like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace BackgroundWorker with BeginInvoke, but it will take some additional code  BackgroundWorker wraps up the management of the background thread in a pretty friendly way.

BeginInvoke can certainly take care of doing work asynchronously.  It's a bit lower level, so you have some more flexibility (at the price of having to do more of the work yourself).